# Good design suggestion for multiple tasks scheduling in C#

Tags: scheduler

I have a service that requires an operation to be performed on an entity status 10 minutes after a specific event has been invoked. During the 10 minute wait, it has to listen for other events that would stop this event altogether so the operation would not be executed.
At any point in time, there could be multiple instances of entities to be handled.

Is there any suggestion as to what possible ways of implementation to create this service?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar in one of my projects that handles users presence management. The rough idea is like this:

1 You have a timer with tick precision that you need (i use 15
    second)

2 Some input event triggers monitoring of an entity and puts entity into the execution queue with time of adding

3 If any canceling event occurs > you remove corresponding entities from the execution queue

4 On timer ticks you check time of adding for each iteam in executionQueue and execute operation for entities that are in there for 10 mins

PS.
you might want to consider using multi-threading / TPL for operations execution.